# Fill in gaps between two dates in a dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to fill in the 'NAs' between two values in a group with the status of the first value. The group is the "label" field, and I want to fill in the 'NA's' in the "status" field.

Here is what I have:

```
     datetime                                      title    label   status           option_title
1  2016-08-06                            Pursuit status:      AIG   Active1                   <NA>
2  2016-08-06 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?      AIG     <NA> 1 - Opportunity Review
3  2016-08-31 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?      AIG     <NA>    2 - Solution Review
4  2016-12-13 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?      AIG     <NA>    4 - Submit Proposal
5  2016-11-14                            Pursuit status:  Allianz   Active1                   <NA>
6  2016-10-27 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?  Allianz     <NA>      Pre-Qualification
7  2017-05-18 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?  Allianz     <NA> 1 - Opportunity Review
8  2017-05-18 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?  Allianz     <NA>      Pre-Qualification
9  2017-08-24                            Pursuit status:  Allianz Inactive1                   <NA>
10 2016-10-27 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?  Allianz     <NA>      Pre-Qualification
11 2016-11-14                            Pursuit status:  Allianz   Active2                   <NA>
12 2016-12-19 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?  Allianz     <NA> 1 - Opportunity Review
13 2017-04-14 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?  Allianz     <NA>    2 - Solution Review
```

Here is what I want:

```
         datetime                                      title    label   status           option_title
1  2016-08-06                            Pursuit status:      AIG   Active1                   <NA>
2  2016-08-06 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?      AIG   Active1 1 - Opportunity Review    
3  2016-08-31 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?      AIG   Active1    2 - Solution Review
4  2016-12-13 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?      AIG   Active1    4 - Submit Proposal
5  2016-11-14                            Pursuit status:  Allianz   Active1                   <NA>
5  2016-10-27 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?  Allianz   Active1      Pre-Qualification
7  2017-05-18 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?  Allianz   Active1 1 - Opportunity Review
8  2017-05-18 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?  Allianz   Active1      Pre-Qualification
9  2017-08-24                            Pursuit status:  Allianz Inactive1                   <NA>
10 2016-10-27 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?  Allianz Inactive1      Pre-Qualification
11 2016-11-14                            Pursuit status:  Allianz   Active2                   <NA>
12 2016-12-19 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?  Allianz   Active2 1 - Opportunity Review
13 2017-04-14 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?  Allianz   Active2    2 - Solution Review
```

Is there a way to do this? I'm thinking the best way would be to get the date of the first status and the date of the second status, and fill in all of the values in-between with the first status.

Comment: That's `zoo::na.locf` and must be a duplicate

Comment: @docendodiscimus When I try this I get the error "Column `status` must be length 5 (the group size) or one, not 4". Any ideas?

Comment: ^ try adding `%>% rowwise %>%` to your pipe before you do the manipulation of status to get the grouping error above to go away.

Comment: for your issue, `tidyr::fill(status)` will do the trick, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tidyr` approach:

It appears you have already solved the ordering issue, so here is code to replicate a minimal example of your dataset.

```
df_orig <- 
    read.table(text = "
             label   status 
               AIG   Active1
               AIG     <NA> 
               AIG     <NA> 
               AIG     <NA> 
           Allianz   Active1
           Allianz     <NA> 
           Allianz     <NA>
           Allianz     <NA> 
           Allianz Inactive1
           Allianz     <NA> 
           Allianz   Active2
           Allianz     <NA> 
           Allianz     <NA> 
                  ", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
    mutate(status = sub("<NA>", NA, status)) # to turn the "<NA>" to active NA's
```

> ```
> > str(df_orig)
> 'data.frame': 13 obs. of  2 variables:
>  $ label : chr  "AIG" "AIG" "AIG" "AIG" ...
>  $ status: chr  "Active1" NA NA NA ...
> ```

Filling into the 'empties'

```
df_filled <-  
    df_orig %>% 
    fill(status)
```

The result:

> ```
> > df_filled
>      label    status
> 1      AIG   Active1
> 2      AIG   Active1
> 3      AIG   Active1
> 4      AIG   Active1
> 5  Allianz   Active1
> 6  Allianz   Active1
> 7  Allianz   Active1
> 8  Allianz   Active1
> 9  Allianz Inactive1
> 10 Allianz Inactive1
> 11 Allianz   Active2
> 12 Allianz   Active2
> 13 Allianz   Active2
> ```